# Changing registry without admins rights windows 10

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-10, registry

Changing registry without admins rights windows 10

What would be the best way add an entry XXX on windows registry with password

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\XXX
```

current permission for everyone are Read.

Tried this :

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\forcerunasinvoker]
@="Run as user without UAC privilege elevation"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\forcerunasinvoker\command]
@="cmd /min /C \"set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start \"\" \"%1\"\""
```

Coming up with Registry error:

> ```
> Cannot import RegFix.reg: not all data was successfully written to the registry. Some keys are open by the system or other processes, or you have insufficient privileges to perform this operations.
> ```

If it cant be done any other option, using powershell, or an executable file, without revealing the password.

Comment: You cannot write to HKLM or HKCR without admin rights. There is no workaround.

Comment: You can't even import a reg file, without elevation! If you do not need to add the registry setting for 'all users', however, simply change `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, _(which really should have been `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes` anyhow)_, to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`. Then you should be able to change the registry using `reg.exe` instead. To find out how to do that, open up a Command Prompt window, type `reg add /?`, press the enter key, and read the help information. Unfortunately though it doesn't help with your `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` setting.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into this link: http://woshub.com/run-program-without-admin-password-and-bypass-uac-prompt/
You can open registry even if it is admin protected with a batch file that runs registry with the RUNASINVOKER compatibility mode, also in this link is a registry file that allows you to run things as admin without UAC coming up. To change elements in the registry it requires administrator privileges since it affects the system configuration like how System32 cannot be edited without administrator permissions.

> You cannot write to HKLM or HKCR without admin rights. There is no workaround

Ken white is correct under normal circumstances but if you use the registry file in the link (which you need administrators rights to import to registry) you can bypass UAC and run registry as admin allowing you to edit the registry.

Comment: Thanks will take a look.